# DSpace Repository: REST API shows 404 error

Tags: java, rest, dspace

I set up a DSpace 6.3 instance for experimenting/development purposes on a Linux Mint 19.1 with a postgresql data base, running on localhost:8080.

XMLUI, SOLR and OAI seem to work fine, but I cannot get the REST API to work. (And also the ORCID integration but that may be connected to the REST problem so I consider that secondary.) I keep getting a 404 error, no matter if I try to access the REST webapp via browser or curl.

I did install the webapp for REST via mvn and ant and I copied the webapp folders to my tomcat9 instance (as explained in https://wiki.lyrasis.org/display/DSDOC6x/Installing+DSpace#InstallingDSpace-InstallationInstructions). 
I also commented out the security-constraint part to deactivate SSL (as explained in https://wiki.lyrasis.org/display/DSDOC6x/REST+API).

The ownership and permission settings are the same as for .../webapps/xmlui, /solr and /oai.

I read that problems can occur with Java 7 (http://dspace.2283337.n4.nabble.com/deploying-the-rest-api-td4692801.html), but I did the installation with Java 8 first and also tried with Java 11, but both did not work.

I do not work with a proxy (as in https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/dspace-tech/rest$20api$20404%7Csort:date/dspace-tech/mnG_tL3Ijrg/58xA20TXAgAJ).

I took a look at the catalina.log and localhost.log in tomcat.
The catalina.log tells me it has something to do with a failed start of listeners:

```
11-Apr-2020 12:23:56.101 INFORMATION [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory [/var/lib/tomcat9/webapps/rest]
11-Apr-2020 12:24:01.153 INFORMATION [main] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanJars At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
11-Apr-2020 12:24:06.521 SCHWERWIEGEND [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal One or more listeners failed to start. Full details will be found in the appropriate container log file
11-Apr-2020 12:24:06.522 SCHWERWIEGEND [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal Context [/rest] startup failed due to previous errors
11-Apr-2020 12:24:06.853 WARNUNG [main] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.clearReferencesThreads The web application [rest] appears to have started a thread named [net.sf.ehcache.CacheManager@5b5d1f9a] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:
 java.base@11.0.6/java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
 java.base@11.0.6/java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:328)
 java.base@11.0.6/java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:527)
 java.base@11.0.6/java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:506)
```

I assume the relevant section of the localhost.log (which I think is the container log file) is:

```
11-Apr-2020 12:24:04.362 INFORMATION [main] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
11-Apr-2020 12:24:06.521 SCHWERWIEGEND [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class [org.dspace.app.util.DSpaceWebappListener]
 org.dspace.core.exception.DatabaseSchemaValidationException: The schema validator returned: Error activating Bean Validation integration
    at org.dspace.core.Context.init(Context.java:170)
    at org.dspace.core.Context.<init>(Context.java:126)
    at org.dspace.app.util.AbstractDSpaceWebapp.register(AbstractDSpaceWebapp.java:74)
    at org.dspace.app.util.DSpaceWebappListener.contextInitialized(DSpaceWebappListener.java:31)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4668)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5136)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:713)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:690)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:695)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory(HostConfig.java:1133)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDirectory.run(HostConfig.java:1868)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectories(HostConfig.java:1045)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:429)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1577)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:309)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal(LifecycleBase.java:424)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setState(LifecycleBase.java:367)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:929)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:831)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1377)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1367)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:140)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:902)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:262)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:423)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:928)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:638)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:350)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:496)

11-Apr-2020 12:24:06.810 SCHWERWIEGEND [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStop Exception sending context destroyed event to listener instance of class [org.dspace.app.util.DSpaceWebappListener]
 org.dspace.core.exception.DatabaseSchemaValidationException: The schema validator returned: Error activating Bean Validation integration
    at org.dspace.core.Context.init(Context.java:170)
    at org.dspace.core.Context.<init>(Context.java:126)
    at org.dspace.app.util.AbstractDSpaceWebapp.deregister(AbstractDSpaceWebapp.java:87)
    at org.dspace.app.util.DSpaceWebappListener.contextDestroyed(DSpaceWebappListener.java:43)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStop(StandardContext.java:4715)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.stopInternal(StandardContext.java:5374)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.stop(LifecycleBase.java:257)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:187)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:713)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:690)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:695)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory(HostConfig.java:1133)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDirectory.run(HostConfig.java:1868)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectories(HostConfig.java:1045)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:429)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1577)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:309)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal(LifecycleBase.java:424)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setState(LifecycleBase.java:367)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:929)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:831)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1377)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1367)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:140)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:902)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:262)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:423)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:928)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:638)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:350)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:496)
```

The dspace, cocoon and solr logs don't seem to contain relevant information as far as I can tell but I can obviously also post them if needed.

Could someone help me understand what these errors mean and what I could do to resolve them - I am a little stuck... If I forgot to include any needed information I am happy to include it of course!

Thanks for even reading...
Anna

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem today. I solved it like this: Tomсat should start under Java 8.
I use DSpace 6.3, Apache Tomcat/9.0.41, CentOS release 8.3.2011